# Windows 11 Upgrade, MySQL unable to start | XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Upgraded to Windows 11, now XAMPP MySQL won't start.

Tried to change ports, run as Admin etc, no luck. MySQL isn't being run in Services by anything else.

Anyone have the solution?

```
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x923f)
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'E:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'E:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 7524752666; transaction id 619031
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from E:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2022-05-14 17:22:32 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

MySQL error above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem as you, running MariaDB on a Windows 11 machine. As the log suggests `delete all aria_log.######## files`.

I had two.
After that MySQL started. Good luck!